# web.config Configuration for Folder Containing Mixed WCF and Domain Services

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-config, forms-authentication, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to lock down security on a folder that contains a mix of WCF and WCF-RIA domain services to only authenticated users, except for the domain services. The folder name is "Services" and contains the following:

```
/Services/Service1.svc
/Services/Service2.svc
/Services/Service3.svc
/Services/AuthenticationService.vb
```

Instead of specifying each service separately, I'd like to deny access to anonymous user to the folder, and then allow anonymous access for the one service.  Since the AuthenticationService.vb doesn't exist after compiling, I'm not sure what to use for the location path.

This is how my current web.config looks:

```
  <location path="Services">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="Services/AuthenticationService.vb">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

I've also tried `"Services/AuthenticationService"` as the path, but that didn't work. What value should I use for `path=`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't secure the folder that contains your services, secure the services themselves using a secure binding. I've [written a blog post](http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2011/08/adding-passwords-to-wcf-service.html) that explains how to do this.

Comment: Actually, you can do either for a directory. I have no problems with the folder allowing only authenticated users and blocking anonymous users. My problem is allowing access to AuthenticationService.vb for anonymous users as "AuthenticationService.vb" doesn't work and neither does "AuthenticationService".

Comment: Sorry for the "drive by" answer that turned out to be wrong. Upon further reflection, I realized that there's a better way to do this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is very interesting and I may have use for it. However, I'm not asking how to implement WCF authentication. In this case, since multiple developers working on the project, I'd like to protect the entire folder so that a developer doesn't miss adding authentication to a new service, meanwhile allowing everyone to have access to the `Services/AuthenticationService.vb` so that they can login. What should the path be for `AuthentcationService.vb` as it becomes a virtual location (compiled into the .dll and the .vb file is removed) once you build the site?

Comment: I can appreciate the problem. I have limited experience with RIA services, but enough to know that there's way too much going on that is hidden. If I were you I would use Fiddler to inspect the http traffic to your domain service.

Comment: I already tried that and it looks like the service is at `/CustomerApplication-Web-AuthenticationService.svc/binary/Login` However, I tried using that as the path too, along with variations, and it didn't work. This has been baffling me for days. It does seem like asp.net thinks its under Services, because as soon as I apply permissions to that folder, AuthenticationService no longer works, and if I list each Service.svc individually, AuthenticationService works. Thanks again for your recommendations.